# Why does my code skip to the end and ignore parts of my code?

Tags: python

Here is the code:

```
print "Welcome to the Database!"

print "Simply type the correponding number to start!"

print """

    1. Add a Student...

    2. Search for a Student...

    3. Edit a Student's Information...

    4. Delete a Student...

    5. Exit...
"""

datab = raw_input("What would you like to do?")

if datab == 1:
    dtabs = open("database.txt", "w")
    que = raw_input("What's the student's name?")
    dtabs.write(que)
    dtabs.close()

    ttrgrp = raw_input("Which tutor group do they belog to?")
```

When I run it in Terminal it prints the what would I like to do but then once an input is taken in the program closes.

Comment: `raw_input` returns a string not `int`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`raw_input()` returns a *string*, but you are comparing against an integer. Python will not coerce strings when comparing:

```
>>> '1' == 1
False
```

Compare against a string here:

```
if datab == '1':
```

as this simplifies validation.

Answer (score 0):

Everything inside of your *if* statement is being skipped, as datab will never be equal to 1 in its integer form. raw_input() will return the value string. Change your if statement to accept 1 as a string:

```
if datab == '1':
    #do something
```